# Freeing memory very slow with Visual debugger

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, memory-management, visual-studio-2013

In our applications we are using a class that utilizes a lot of big Qt containers. If objects of that class are destroyed while a Visual Studio debugger is attached to the process, freeing of the memory is extremly slow (multiple minutes). Still it works fine but simply very slow.

Some time ago I already could confirm that the debugger's memory checking is reponsible for this. It is a known issue.

I worked around this issue by simply stopping the application by debugger if it is stuck in freeing memory or by starting it without an attached debugger.

However now I need to debug code that periodically deallocates such objects. Of course it works but it is inacceptable slow and since I need to do a lot of cycles I need a better solution.

Is there any way to disable heap memory checking in VS2013 debugger? Or is there a way to exclude some variables from those checks?

Comment: Even if you have confirmed that the MSVC's memory checking is the reason for this slow-down I'd still look into your own code to see if there are inefficiencies that cause that(like unnecessary object creation/deletion?)

Comment: That's the first thing I checked. Unfortunately I could not change the code in a way that it does not trigger the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried another solution. Setting the environment variable _NO_DEBUG_HEAP to 1 actually solves my problem.

This can be done on system level (using a common environment variable editor e.g. REE) or on application level by setting the Visual Studio project property Debugging/Environment to "_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1".

I found this information in an answer to my question that unfortunately isn't visible anymore (I suppose it was deleted by moderators). It contained [this](http://preshing.com/20110717/the-windows-heap-is-slow-when-launched-from-the-debugger/) link that was actually very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[`_CrtSetDbgFlag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs.aspx) controls what kinds of checking the debug heap does.

It's possible your code (or perhaps a library you're using) has cranked up the checking level.  For example, you can have it check the integrity of the heap on every allocation and deallocation.  That can cause a huge slowdown.  Don't use `_CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF` unless you actually need it to find a specific memory problem.

For basic leak checking, which generally isn't a huge performance penalty, you need only `(_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF | _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF)`.

Comment: I tried calling _CrtSetDbgFlag(0); for testing but the behaviour didn't change.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work with vs2019+ because ```_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG)``` returns 1, so```_CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF``` is disabled by default but debugging stays very slow